# How to centrally define IComparable on abstract (interface) types in F#

Tags: .net, interop, f#, interface, set

This question is kind of the next level of [F# Set using custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895769/f-set-using-custom-class) -- I want to define IComparable for a generic interface.

I have an arbitrary set of types which implement a shared metadata exchange interface, `ITree`. I want to compare across these types, using only the exposed data in `ITree`.

I realize this stuff is not exactly idiomatic F#, but I'm trying to interop with existing C# and VB code, so I want to use .NET interfaces and comparison where possible.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

// Simplified "generic" metadata type that all implementers agree on
type ITree =
  abstract Path: string with get, set
  abstract ModifyDate: DateTime with get, set

type Thing1(path, date) =
  interface ITree with
    member x.Path = path
    member x.ModifyDate = date

// In reality, the types implementing ITree are going to
// come from different external assemblies
type Thing2(path, date) =
  interface ITree with
    member x.Path = path
    member x.ModifyDate = date

let d1 = DateTime.Now
let d2 = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2.0)
let xs : seq<ITree> = Seq.cast [ Thing1("/stuff", d1); Thing1("/dupe", d1); Thing1("/dupe", d1) ]
let ys : seq<ITree> = Seq.cast [ Thing2("/stuff", d2); Thing2("/dupe", d1) ]

// Then I would like to take advantage of F# Sets
// to do comparison across these things
let xset = Set.ofSeq xs
let yset = Set.ofSeq ys

let same = Set.intersect xset yset
let diffs = (xset + yset) - same
```

Now the actual problem: this does not compile because `ITree` doesn't yet implement `IComparable`. I need a custom comparison that helps with clock skew and eventually other things.

Is there a way I can define the comparison function **on `ITree` directly** so that all the other assemblies don't need to think about it, and can just provide their data?

If I try to do

```
type ITree =
  abstract Path: string with get, set
  abstract ModifyDate: DateTime with get, set
    interface IComparable<ITree> with
      let Subtract (this: ITree) (that: ITree) =
        this.ModifyDate.Subtract(that.ModifyDate)
      match compare (this.Path, this.ParentPath) (that.Path, this.ParentPath) with
      | 0 ->
        // Paths are identical, so now for a stupid timespan comparison
        match abs (Subtract this that).TotalSeconds with
        | x when x > 60.0  -> int x
        | _ -> 0
      | x -> x
```

The compiler thinks `ITree` is no longer an abstract interface, or something confusing.

Now, I could create a base type that all of the implementors must share, but I don't want to do that because those other types really just need to expose their data on this interface, they already exist, and may already have a base class for some other reason.

Possibly I can use `IComparer<T>`, like

```
type ITreeComparer =      
  interface IComparer<ITree> with
    member x.Compare(this, that) = ...
```

But then I have no idea how to tell the `Set...` functions to use that IComparer.

(I assume that once I figure out how to apply `IComparer<T>`, the same methods will work for `IEqualityComparer<T>` as needed.)

---

**Edit:** I can do

```
let x = new HashSet<ITree>(a |> Seq.cast<ITree>, new ITreeEqualityComparer())
```

To use the normal .NET collections, which should be good enough for this problem; however, I would still like to know if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a wrapper type if you want to store the data in an F# Set (Set is not designed to work with custom IComparers).  So you could do e.g.

```
type TreeWithComparer(tree:ITree) =
    member this.Data = tree
    interface IComparable with ...
        // define the custom logic you need
```

and then store those wrapper objects in the Set.

Comment: Nice, that is what I need to do then. I just started trying to work with HashSet<T>, and man, the signatures are scary... UnionWith(seq<T>) : unit -- auuuugh! in-place modification!

Comment: This works perfectly. No ugly code duplication. Now I only wish I was smart enough to think of that all on my lonesome...