# Does F# use lazy evaluation by default?

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation

Does F# even have lazy evaluation?

Comment: It seems like [a lazy question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee353813.aspx) :P.

Answer (score 9):

F# is not lazy-by-default (a la Haskell). But explicit laziness is available. See [Lazy Computations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233247.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide an example in F# of a lazy prime number sequence, and how to take `n` primes from it?

Comment: The `Lazy` type computes a single result. You want a sequence (`IEnumerable<'T>`). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4629734/162396) for some examples.